# strcat is giving me a segmentation fault error

Tags: c, arrays, char, append, strcat

After verifying that strcat is where the error occurs, I then check the previous example in my assignment. In my previous examples I use strcat(actually strncat) in the same fashion as I do for my following code. I am not too sure.

The purpose of my program is to loop through "string" and remove any occurances the character 'c' from string.

main.c:

```
 char string[100]={0}, c[3];

 printf("Enter a String: ");
 fgets(string, 100, stdin);
 if (string[98] == '\n' && string[99] == '\0') { while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); }

 printf("Enter a Char: ");
 fgets(c, 2, stdin);
 while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');

 rmchr(string, c[0]);
```

header:

```
rmchr(char *string, char c)
{ 
  int i=0;
  char *word[100];

  int s = strlen(string);

  for(i=0; i<=(s-2); i++)
  {
    if(string[i] != c)
    {
      strcat(word, string[i]);
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: `strcat(word, string[i]);` should have failed to compile.

Comment: GCC sometimes declares string functions as intrinsics even when the programmer forgot to `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: You have the rmchr function in a header file? If so, it should be moved to a C file.

Comment: By the way, I would use fewer magic numbers like 100 and more constants like `LONGESTWORD` or expressions like `sizeof(array)` (but not pointer!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *word[100];
```

It will hold a string in your program so use:

```
char word[100];
```

that is, an array of `char` instead of an array of `char *`.

Then `strcat` concatenates to a string but `word` is not initialized. Make it a string with:

```
word[0] = '\0';
```

Then `string[i]` is a character but `strcat` needs pointers to character arguments: to use a pointer use `&string[i]`.

Finally the problem in your `rmchr` function is it has to return something, either through the arguments or via a return statement but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one point to mention here, like

1. `rmchr()` definition should have a return type, maybe `void` if you're not returning anything.

   <sup>[*FWIW, In that case, I wounder, how you'll make use of the local variable `word`*]</sup>
2. inside `rmchr()`, `word` needs to be an array of `char`s, not `char` pointers. You need to change `char * word[100]` to `char word[100]`.
3. In `strcat()`, both the arguments, needs to be a pointer. You need to use `&string[i]`, in that case.

Comment: @user2864740 absolutely, but this is the most basic requirement. Any decent compiler would have screamed, otherwise. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to compile fine but your code doesnt do quite what you said you wanted, "The purpose of my program is to loop through "string" and remove any occurances the character 'c' from string.". the function doesn't remove the character or return a copy of the string with the character excluded. I wrote a function that copies the string after removing the character and returns pointer to it. below is your code a bit modified and under it is my function

```
//Just a compilable version of your code, not sure if it does what u want
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void rmchr(char *string, char c)   
{ 
    int i=0;
    char word[100];

    int s = (int)strlen(string);

    for(i=0; i<=(s-2); i++)
    {
        if(string[i] != c)
        {
            strcat(word, (char *)(&string[i]));
        }
    }  
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char string[100] = {0}, c[3];
    char ch;

    printf("Enter a String: ");
    fgets(string, 100, stdin);
    if (string[98] == '\n' && string[99] == '\0') { 
       while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n'); 
    }

    printf("Enter a Char: ");
    fgets(c, 2, stdin);
    while ( (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');

    rmchr(string, c[0]); 

    return 0;
}
```

There you go, with a demo main

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* rmchr(char *string, char ch)
{ 
    int counter = 0;
    int new_size = 0;
    char corrected_string[100];

    while (string[counter] != '\n' && string[counter] != '\0' && string[counter] != EOF)  {
        if (string[counter] != ch) {
            corrected_string[new_size] = string[counter];
            new_size++;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    char *new_string = (char *)malloc((new_size+1) * sizeof(char));

    for (int j = 0; j <= new_size; j++) {
        new_string[j] = corrected_string[j];
    }
    return new_string;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char *s = "The char 'c' will be removed";
    char *new = rmchr(s, 'c');
    printf("%s", new);
    return 0;
}
```